# Tabela no IReporter não aparece na aplicação

Tags: java, relatório

Senhores boa tarde!

Estou em um mato sem cachorro e não consigo achar mais soluções para o meu problema, vejam:

No meu formulário do Ireport utilizo o componente Table. Criei um dataset que é responsável em buscar itens de um contrato em questão. A consulta que coloquei nesse dataset é a seguinte:

```html
SELECT ci.grupo||'.'||ci.subgrupo||'.'||ci.codigo AS material, ci.descricao AS descricao, ci.unidade AS unidade,
cri.quantidade AS requerido, cra.quantidade_atendida AS atendido
FROM compras.contrato_item ci
LEFT JOIN compras.contrato_requisicao_item cri ON (ci.ano = cri.ano AND ci.contrato = cri.contrato AND ci.item = cri.item)
LEFT JOIN compras.contrato_requisicao_item_atendido cra ON (cri.ano_requisicao = cra.ano_requisicao AND cri.requisicao = cra.requisicao AND cri.ano = cra.ano AND cri.contrato = cra.contrato AND cri.item = cra.item)
WHERE  cri.ano_requisicao = $P!{PARAM_ANO_REQUISICAO} AND cri.requisicao = $P!{PARAM_REQUISICAO} AND cri.ano = $P!{PARAM_ANO_CONTRATO} AND cri.contrato = '$P!{PARAM_CONTRATO}'
```

O detalhe é que esses parâmetros são apontados para os parâmetros principais configurados no IReport.

Agora que vem o problema. Quando rodo no Preview do IReport o relatório é montado com sucesso e esse componente Tabela lista todos os Itens da tabela, mas quando mando o .jasper para a minha aplicação java pra gerar o relatório a partir da aplicação a tabela não lista os itens. Acredito que seja um problema desses parametros, pois quando eu seto esses parâmetros de maneira manual e mando o .jasper para a aplicação a tabela mostra os itens.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?
Abraços!

Comment: Boa tarde André, você conseguiu resolver a questão de exibir o conteúdo da tua tabela?

Comment: Boa Tarde, tem muito tempo já. Mas lembro que o problema era um erro meu. No codigo JAVA eu estava passando o parâmetro com um nome diferente... Era alguma coisa assim...

Comment: Mas você conseguiu exibir algo no espaço "Details" do relatório? Por que tudo que eu coloco ali não aparece no meu relatório, mesmo que seja um Texto Estatico

Comment: Coloquei as tabelas dinâmicas em Detail 1 e elas foram exibidas!

Comment: Bah será que tu poderia me mostrar como você configurou o seu arquivo jrxml no Jasper Studio? Por que eu já tentei de *N* maneiras e nada da certo

Comment: Me passa seu email que te envio

Comment: romualdo.s.rs@gmail.com Muito obrigado mesmo @Andre, vou ficar no aguardo do teu email então